# Use Two Conjection Table in a Single Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a blog post system in which I am using following table structure :-

```
blog_category
category_id, category_name, enabled, created_date

blog_post
post_id,title,article, author_id,date_published

post_category
category_id, post_id 

blog_tag
tag_id, tag_name

post_tag
id,tag_id,post_id

post_related
id, post_id, post_related_id

blog_comment
comment_id, post_id, is_reply_to_id,comment,user_id
```

My questions ARE:

1. How to get this type of output in a single query

   `title,author_name,article,total_comments,post_tags`
2. How to insert records in post_related table to show the related post when select a   particular post.

   I trying like this but it show `unknown column bp.post_id`

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE blog_get_posts_in_category(
       IN inCategoryId INT, IN inShortPostDescriptionLength INT,
       IN inPostsPerPage INT, IN inStartItem INT)
       BEGIN
       PREPARE statement FROM
       "SELECT bp.post_id, bp.title,(select count(*) from blog_comment where post_id=bp.post_id) as total_comments,   
       IF(LENGTH(bp.article) <= ?,
       bp.article,
       CONCAT(LEFT(bp.article, ?),
       '...')) AS article,
       DATE_FORMAT(bp.date_published,'%d %M %Y at %h:%i:%s %p') as date_published, bp.banner_image,ba.display_name     
       FROM blog_post bp
       INNER JOIN blog_post_to_category bpc
       ON bpc.post_id = bp.post_id     
       INNER JOIN blog_author ba
       ON ba.id = bp.author_id
       WHERE bpc.category_id = ?  and enabled=1
       ORDER BY bp.post_id DESC
       LIMIT ?, ?";
       SET @p1 = inShortPostDescriptionLength;
       SET @p2 = inShortPostDescriptionLength;
       SET @p3 = inCategoryId;
       SET @p4 = inStartItem;
       SET @p5 = inPostsPerPage;
       EXECUTE statement USING @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5;
       END$$
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1:

This is not really clear from the question, so lets suppose that 
- blog_author table looks like
author_id, author_name, ...
- total_comments is the number of all the comments belonging to a blog post.
- post_tags could be one string containing all the post_tags related to a blog post (e.g. as a csv).

Then, a query could be:

```
SELECT
  bp.post_id as pid, bp.title, a.author_name, bp.article, bc.total_comments, pt.post_tags
FROM blog_post bp
LEFT JOIN blog_author a ON bp.author_id=a.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) as total_comments
  FROM blog_comment
  GROUP BY post_id) bc
  ON bc.post_id=bp.post_id 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_id SEPARATOR ',') AS post_tags
  FROM post_tag
  GROUP BY post_id) pt
  ON pt.post_id=bp.post_id;
```

Q2:

Here, the query seems to be OK. I even tried it myself and I got no error message about the bp.post_id. Just one idea that the subquery with the total_comments could be avoided using the join (with the blog_comment table) that I show in my previous query.

But this procedure/query does something different than the question supposed to be about. (It does not even have any reference to the blog_related table.)

Comment: Yes this procedure does not belong to blog_related table. I does not know the concept how to insert records in blog_related table when I created a new post and how to show back them as related posts.

Comment: it seems to be too trivial, but what is the problem with `insert post_related (post_id, post_related_id) values (<<the id of the post>>, <<the id of the related post>>)` ??? you just need to be sure that the `id` column is autoincremented and you need to know the ids of the posts that are related. of course, the latter one depends on your workflow...

Comment: Sir Thanks for your kind support but your suggested query what is the role of post_category, post_tag tables because these tables are connection tables and searched based on a particular category.

Comment: One Last favour Sir How to show tags names not ids below posts with this query.

Comment: I guess that you have a tag table then, but you forgot to mention it in the question. (this is why I used it in the query) So if you have a tag table too, join that table on the tag_id and use the tag name in the group_concat.